# Insert record if the id is not present in db

Tags: php

I want to ask about inserting a record into `db` like if we give the `id` in url throught `$Getn` and check if the data of `id n` is present in table then it must update else it must insert the data ?

how can we do it in PHP plz help me

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like

```
<?php

$n = $_GET["n"]; 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfRecords FROM table WHERE id = '$n'";
mysql_query($query);

if ($numberOfRecords == 0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO [...]");
else
    mysql_query("UPDATE [...]");
```

Comment: That, or some version of IF EXISTS (SELECT...)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. Simply check id is set or not

```
if(isset($_GET['n']) && !empty($_GET['n'])){
  //your update query is here
}else{
  //your insert query is here
}
```